Why height parameter is not working in tb.Label Widget?
I am using tb.Lable from ttkbootstarp but i am not able use height, bd attribute
The error ->
 File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1692, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-height"

This is my code ->
from tkinter import *
import ttkbootstrap as tb

class Root(tb.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(themename='superhero')

        self.frame = Frame(self.canvas)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        Slot(self.frame)


class Slot(tb.Label):
    SlotList = [] 

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        Slot.SlotList.append(self)
        self.config(width=40, height=20, bd=1, relief="solid", bg="white")
        self.grid(padx=30, pady=30)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = Root()
    App.mainloop()
`

I have tried too much to debug it but it is not working, the problem might be with tb.Lable as i remove tb. it is working properly but i want to use it with tb.Lable

because the height of a Label is the fontsize.

tb.Label is actually ttk.Label which does not support height option.  Note that it does not support bd as well.  If you just want some space between the text and the border, use padding option.


Why height parameter is not working in tb.Label Widget?

but it is not working, the problem might be with tb.Lable as i remove tb. it is working properly but i want to use it with tb.Lable


The problem can be fixed.

Add Label in def __init__(self)
Remove parameter self.frame in Slot() callable. And add fontsize.

Snippet:
class Root(tb.Window):

        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__(themename='superhero')
    
            self.frame = Frame(self)
            self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    
            tb.Label(self, text='python is great', font=("Helvetica", 18)).grid()
            Slot()
    

Screenshot:

